# 地図上にA点からB点まで矢印を引きたい

Tags: python, python3

前回、同じ内容の質問を申し上げましたが、コードを何も載せなかったので本当に申し訳ございませんでした。
今回はコードの一部を載せ、再質問いたします。
著作権のためコードの一部しか載せないところご了解お願い致します。

```
        utc              latA      lonA        latB         lonB
2020-04-26 09:40:00 34.659167   135.299167  34.693384   135.303307
2020-04-26 09:56:00 34.613921   135.217850  34.614219   135.218978
```

A点はutcに該当する船の位置を示し、B点はA点における潮流の影響を作用した予想位置を示します。
A点の位置からB点まで矢印を引き、潮流の動き表示する作業をしたいですが、出来るところまで、作業してみましたが、上手くいけなくて質問します。

以下のような矢印を引きたいです。青い点がA点、赤い点がB点を示します。

黒い矢印が作りたいものになります。

ご答えよろしくお願いいたします。

**作りたい図の構成:**

[image: 作りたい図の構成]

**現状のソースコード:**

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(40,60))  

# 上限／下限の設定
lat_min = data['latA'].min()-0.1
lat_max = data['latA'].max()+0.1
lon_min = data['lonA'].min()-0.1
lon_max = data['lonA'].max()+0.1

# 緯度・経度の範囲／単位を取得
lats = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max, 40)  # 緯度 
lons = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, 40) # 経度 

# グリッドデータに変換
x, y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

# Basemapオブジェクトの作成
bmap = Basemap(
    projection='merc',
    resolution='h',
    llcrnrlon=lon_min,
    llcrnrlat=lat_min,
    urcrnrlon=lon_max,
    urcrnrlat=lat_max)
 
# 陸地の塗り潰し
bmap.fillcontinents(color='lightgray', lake_color='white',zorder = 0)
# 緯線を描く
bmap.drawparallels(lats, labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10, color='gray')
# 経線を描く
bmap.drawmeridians(lons, labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10, color='gray')

latssA=np.array(data['latA'])
lonssA=np.array(data['lonA'])

lat1 = latssA
lon1 = lonssA

latssB=np.array(data['latB'])
lonssB=np.array(data['lonB'])

lat2 = latssB
lon2 = lonssB

xunknown,yunknown = bmap(lon1, lat1) 
xunknown2,yunknown2 = bmap(lon2, lat2) 

bmap.plot(xunknown, yunknown, 'bo', markersize=11)
bmap.plot(xunknown2, yunknown2, 'ro', markersize=20)
```

Comment: 現状で、どこまで出来ているのですか？
緯線、経線が引かれたマップは表示できているのですか？

「出来るところまで、作業してみましたが、上手くいけなくて質問します」じゃぁ、何も判りません。

何に困っているのかを具体的に説明してください。

Comment: 地図上に点A、点Bは表示できるようになりましたが、二つの点を矢印で結びたいです。黒い矢印のようにA点からB点に引きたいです。

Comment: 現状でできているところはA,B点の表示のみです。黒い矢印はペイントで貼りました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[quiver(x, y, u, v, *args, **kwargs)](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.quiver)というメソッドで出来ます。

日本語化解説はこちら。
[Pythonで世界地図(matplotlib basemap toolkit翻訳)-3](https://qiita.com/ty21ky/items/e98127203bf015f547d4)

*args, **kwargsに指定できるものはこちら。
[matplotlib.pyplot.quiver](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html)

処理的には以下で、`zorder`が指定してあるのは矢印の元と先が丸に隠れたため。
場所や方向によっては何かもう少し複雑な計算が必要かもしれませんが。

```
u = np.subtract(xunknown2, xunknown)
v = np.subtract(yunknown2, yunknown)
bmap.quiver(xunknown, yunknown, u, v, scale=1, units='xy', zorder=3)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげさまできれいに矢印が引けました。本当に助かりました。